# Tutorial on writing rss reader on qt

Tags: rss-reader

I came across a tutorial on creating rss readers, but the article was very old. And the code link doesn't work. Perhaps someone made an rss reader on the Qt? 
P.S. Actually here is the tutorial https://www.linuxformat.com/tuxradarchive/content/code-project-create-qt-rss-reader I also tried to connect the slots: from the button to the WebView, and from TreeWidget to the MainWindow, but for some reason it did not work

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/QuiteRSS/quiterss

> QuiteRSS is a open-source cross-platform RSS/Atom news feeds reader written on Qt/C++